# TypeError: abrir.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema con este archivo **`.js`** ¿Cuál puede ser el inconveniente? me dice:

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

He intentado realizar cambios pero aún no logro resolver, el código es para hacer una ventana modal.

```
let cerrar = document.querySelectorAll("close")[0];
let abrir = document.querySelectorAll("nuevoSalon")[0];
let modal = document.querySelectorAll("modal")[0];
let modalC = document.querySelectorAll("modal-container")[0];

abrir.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    modalC.style.opacity = "1";
    modalC.style.visibility = "visible";
    modal.classList.toggle("modal-close");
});

cerrar.addEventListener("click",function () {
    modal.classList.toggle("modal-close");
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        modalC.style.opacity = "0";
        modalC.style.visibility = "hidden";
    },1000)
})

window.addEventListener(function(e) {
    console.log(e.target)
    if(e.target == modalC){
        modal.classList.toggle("modal-close");
    
        setTimeout(function () {
            modalC.style.opacity = "0";
            modalC.style.visibility = "hidden";
        },1000)
    }
})
```

Comment: eres un capo mi hermano, me faltaba aparte de tener el indice por fuera del ( ) el . antes del close. soy nuevo aqui, mil gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Perfecto, pude encontrar la solución, el problema general estaba en dejar el índice por fuera de los paréntesis y faltaba el . antes del `close`, comparto mi código solucionado.

```
let cerrar = document.querySelectorAll(".close")[0];
let abrir = document.querySelectorAll(".nuevoSalon")[0];
let modal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal")[0];
let modalC = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-container")[0];

abrir.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    modalC.style.opacity = "1";
    modalC.style.visibility = "visible";
    modal.classList.toggle("modal-close");
});

cerrar.addEventListener("click",function () {
    modal.classList.toggle("modal-close");
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        modalC.style.opacity = "0";
        modalC.style.visibility = "hidden";
    },1000)
})

window.addEventListener(function(e) {
    console.log(e.target)
    if(e.target == modalC){
        modal.classList.toggle("modal-close");
    
        setTimeout(function () {
            modalC.style.opacity = "0";
            modalC.style.visibility = "hidden";
        },1000)
    }
})
```